# Scroll Through Layers of ListLinePlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, animation, visualization, user-interface

I like the default functionality of `ListLinePlot3D`'s layering of 2-d data plots, as seen below with 4 layers.

```
ListLinePlot3D[
{{2.1, 2.9, 2.8, 1.9, 1.1, 1.2, 2.1}, 
{2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 2.2}, 
{2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7, 2.3}, 
{2.4, 1., 2.6, 2.4, 1., 2.6, 2.4}}, 
Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: ListLinePlot3D pic]

However, this visual becomes unwieldy with many layers. I would love to have the ability to "scroll through" layers in groups of some size k.

For example, say I have 50 layers total and I do not want to show all 50 of them at once because the visuals would look overwhelming. I would like to show k=5 layers at any one time, and then scroll through the 50 layers, 5 at a time. So at the beginning, layers (1-5) would show. When I scroll a bit further, layers (2-6) would show. After scrolling through to the end, layers (46-50) would show.

### Bonus Points

What would really be cool is to have the group of say, k=5 layers showing and then, say, j=2 more "hanging layers" in front and in back showing, but these layers are translucent. This way the user can see better what he is scrolling through. For example, the plot with its axes would be fixed in the center, and then the data layers would roll through, whereby, say layers 11-15 can be fully seen in the plot, and layers 9 and 10 are translucent in front, while layers 16 and 17 are translucent in back.

After scrolling, layers 23-27 can be fully seen in the plot, and layers 21 and 22 are translucent in front, while layers 28 and 29 are translucent in back. In the beginning, no translucent hanging layers would be in front and at the end, no translucent hanging layers would be in back.

This is *somewhat* similar to how time machine on Macs visually slides between windows, if you are familiar (see [8:10 here](https://youtu.be/Cd2YaBCXpaM?t=490)).

I am open to other nice, visually appealing variations or ideas.

### Update

The answers so far are great. I am also wondering if the scrolling can be smooth, so that the layers look like they are smoothly scrolling through the axes/box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomReal[5, {50, 10}];
```

For smooth scrolling

1. Create a plot of all data using `ListLinePlot3D` and post-process to add filling polygons with matching colors:

```
addFilling = ReplaceAll[Line[x_] :> 
 {Line[x], Opacity[.2], EdgeForm[], 
  Polygon[Join[{Append[0] @ x[[1, 1,;; 2]]}, x[[1]], {Append[0] @ x[[1,- 1,;; 2]]}]]}]

plot = addFilling @ ListLinePlot3D[MapIndexed[Tooltip]@data,
  SphericalRegion -> True, 
  PlotRegion -> {{0, 1}, {-.2, 1.2}},
  Boxed -> {Back, Bottom, Left},
  ViewPoint -> {3, -1, 1}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  AxesEdge -> {{1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}},
  PlotRangePadding ->.5, 
  Ticks -> {Range[10], Range[50], Range[0,6]} ,
  PlotStyle -> (ColorData[97] /@ Range[50])];
```

2. Use `plot` with `Show` with a smoothly varying `PlotRange`:

```
Manipulate[Show[plot, PlotRange ->{{0, 10}, {t, t + ww}, {0, 6}}], 
 {{ww, 5, "window width"}, Range[3, 20], SetterBar}, 
 {{t, 0, "animation"}, 0, .5 + Length@data - ww, .05,
    Animator, DisplayAllSteps -> True, AnimationRunning -> False, AnimationRate -> 20}, 
 Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

**Notes:**

- The reason for post-processing to add polygons: If, instead, we use the option `Filling` in `ListLinePlot3D` with many lines there is a mismatch between line and polygon styles (This seems to be a bug).
- We explicitly map `ColorData[97]` on `Range[50]` to get distinct colors for each line. If we use the default plot style (or use `PlotStyle - > 97`)  the colors *cycle* thru a shorter list giving duplicate colors. (Furthermore, when `Filling -> Axis` is used, the filling colors are also cyclic but with a different cycle - possible source of / contributor to the bug mentioned above).
- The option `SphericalRegion` and explicit `PlotRange` and `Ticks` is to avoid flickering in animation.
- The option `PlotRegion` is used to trim the white space above and below the main plot.

Comment: This is great. Do you happen to know why the filling color for layers 11 and 12 don't match the curve color? They are the only layers like that.

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan, good eye-sight for JustSomeOldMan:)  Don't know why -- I will check.

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan, the mismatch between line and filling colors seems to be a bug (actually many other layers have the same issue but is takes harder squinting to see them). I updated with a work-around that avoids this issue.

Answer (score 10):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

data = RandomReal[2.5, {50, 7}];

Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot3D[data[[n ;; n + 4]],
  Filling -> Axis,
  DataRange -> {{1, Length[data[[1]]]}, {n, n + 4}}],
 {{n, 1}, 1, Length[data] - 4, 1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant and efficient.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
ClearAll[llp3D]
llp3D[dt_, col_: 97][i1_, i2_, pad_: 1, o : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{min = Min[dt], 
   xyz = Select[i1 - pad <= #[[1, 2]] <= i2 + pad &]@
      MapIndexed[Flatten[{Reverse@#2, #}] &, dt, {2}], 
   colors = AssociationThread[Range[Length @ dt], 
      Switch[col, _List, col, 
        _Integer, ColorData[col] /@ Range[Length @ dt], 
        _String,  ColorData[col] /@ Rescale[Range[Length@dt]]]]}, 
  Graphics3D[Map[{JoinForm["Round"], CapForm["Round"], Thin, colors@#[[1, 2]],
      #[[1, 2]] /. {Alternatives @@ Range[i1, i2] -> Tube[#, .05], _ ->  Line[#]}, 
      EdgeForm[], Opacity[#[[1, 2]] /. {Alternatives @@ Range[i1, i2] -> .2, _ -> .05}],
      Polygon[Join[{Append[min]@#[[1, ;; 2]]}, #, {Append[min]@#[[-1, ;; 2]]}]]} &]@xyz,
   o, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> True, 
   Ticks -> {Automatic, Range[i1 - pad, i2 + pad], Automatic}, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomReal[5, {50, 10}];

llp3D[data][2, 15, 2, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> {Back, Bottom, Left}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.01], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
pad = 2; ww = 4; nmax = Length@data;

yrange[d_, ww_, pad_] := {Max[1, Min[nmax - ww - 2 pad, # - pad]], 
   Min[nmax, Max[# + ww + pad, ww + 2 pad + 1]]} &; 

Manipulate[llp3D[data][m, m + ww, pad, 
  ViewPoint -> {3, -1, 1}, 
  ImageSize -> Large,
  Boxed -> {Back, Bottom, Left}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 1, 
  PlotRange -> {All, yrange[data, ww, pad]@m, Round[MinMax@data]}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Range @@ yrange[data, ww, pad]@m, Range[0, 6]}], 
 Grid[{{Dynamic[Pane[StringPadLeft[ToString@m, 3], ImageSize -> {21, 15}]], 
    Control@{{m, 1, ""}, 1, nmax - ww, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
    Dynamic[Pane[StringPadLeft[ToString[m + ww], 3], 
      ImageSize -> {21, 15}]]}}, 
   Spacings -> 1, Alignment -> {{Right, Right, Right}, Center}]]
```

[image]

The animation at the top produced using

```
frames = Table[llp3D[data][m, m + ww, pad, ViewPoint -> {3, -1, 1}, 
   ImageSize -> Large, Boxed -> {Back, Bottom, Left}, PlotRangePadding -> 1, 
   PlotRange -> {All, yrange[data, ww, pad]@m, Round[MinMax@data]}, 
   Ticks -> {Automatic, Range @@ yrange[data, ww, pad]@m, Range[0, 6]}], 
  {m, 1, 45}];

Export["llp3dwindows.gif", frames]
```